# Why does the program hang in WSL?

Tags: c++, c, linux, signals, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have the following code in my program.

```
Thread* t = arg->thread;
//at this point, the new thread is being executed.
t->myId = TGetId();
void* (*functor)(void*) = t->functor;
void* fArg = arg->arg;
nfree(arg);
_INFO_PRINTF(1, "Launching thread with ID: %d", t->myId);
sigset_t mask;
sigfillset(&mask);         //fill mask with all signals
sigdelset(&mask, SIGUSR1); // allow SIGUSR1 to get to the thread.
sigdelset(&mask, SIGUSR2); // allow SIGUSR2 to get to the thread.
pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL); //block some sigs

struct sigaction act;
memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
act.sa_handler = TSignalHandler;
act.sa_mask = mask;
if(sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL))
{
    _ERROR_PRINT(1, "Could not set signal action.");
    return NULL;
}
if(sigaction(SIGUSR2, &act, NULL))
{
    _ERROR_PRINT(1, "Could not set signal action.");
    return NULL;
}
void* ret = functor(fArg);
t->hasReturned = true;
return ret;
```

The thread that executes this code will properly call the signal handler when on native linux.  The problem is that on Windows Subsystem for Linux, the program hangs with the SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2 is sent via pthread_kill which sends signals to a thread.  Why does this work on native ubuntu (via VMWARE WORKSTATION 14) and debian and fedora, but NOT WSL?

Comment: WSL bug maybe??

Comment: Do any functions return an error?

Comment: What is `TSignalHandler`? What is `functor`?

Comment: As one might see on line 4, functor is a function pointer with type `void* (*) (void*)`. And as one might know from the sigaction struct, `TSignalHandler` is a void functiong taking one int parameter.

Comment: If you run the program under gdb, can you show us what line of code makes it hang, and get a backtrace?

Comment: I just tried it, it DOES NOT hang in GDB.  So, it hangs in WSL without GDB, but runs fine in native linux without GDB, but runs fine in WSL WITH gdb.

Comment: I understand your code executes functions. But by being evasive about what they do, it decreases the likelihood that you will get useful help. MCVE please.

Comment: @jxh "I understand your code executes functions" made me LOL at myself. Yes, I misunderstood the point of your comment. functor is an empty loop and TSignalHandler just prints a message with printf.

Comment: It is probably not your issue, but calling `printf` from a signal handler is a bad idea. The general purpose C library functions are often not reentrant, and can hang if the signal is being handled while it is in the middle of uncompleted library call itself.

Comment: I recommend that when you get it to hang, induce a core file (e.g., by killing the process with SIGTRAP) or attach gdb to the running process. Find the backtrace.

Comment: @lxh Problem solved thanks you your GDB comment,I assumed the problem was WSL because it ran fine on native linux.I was wrong (way wrong). the problem was that on native linux, the new thread had time to set up before the main thread started using it.On WSL the main thread started using the new thread before it had time to setup, causing the new thread to get used too soon.  This caused the thread to behave in an undefined manner and the main thread would stay joined for ever.  Thanks again jxh If you submit an answer about attaching GDB ill accept it.

Comment: also @jhx, I will make sure not to call printf in a release, they are just for debugging atm, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a hanging bug that you cannot reproduce when running within the debugger, you can attach the debugger to the running process after you reproduce the hang. This won't let you observe the variables changing as you lead to the hang, but at least you get the stack trace of exactly where the hang is occurring.

Once you know the process id of the hung process (assume it's 12345), you can use:

> ```
> $ gdb -p 12345
> ```

Or, you can kill the process with a signal that will cause a core to be generated. I like to use `SIGTRAP`, since it is easy to distinguish from a `SIGSEGV`.

> ```
> $ kill -SIGTRAP 12345
> ```

And then you can use `gdb` to discover what the process was hanging on.

The advantage of attaching to the running process is that the process is still live. This allows you to call functions from the debugger, which may provide easier access to diagnostics built into your program. The core file preserves the error, which is beneficial if the hanging bug is difficult to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me find my issue, which was my own fault and not wsl. Race condition, in code that was called by posted code.